# Как в TypeScript перегрузить конструктор?

Tags: typescript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не смог найти как. Мне нужно что бы было 2 конструктора с разными параметрами.

```js
class Company {
    //Companies": [ { "company_ID": 1, "name": "Компания1", "description": "Описание компании", "logo": "Лого" } 
    companyId: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    logo: string;

    constructor(bd: LocalDb, id: number) {
        var sid = String(id);
        this.companyId = Number(bd.getInfo(['Companies', sid, 'company_ID']));
        this.name = String(bd.getInfo(['Companies', sid, 'name']));
        this.description = String(bd.getInfo(['Companies', sid, 'description']));
        this.logo = String(bd.getInfo(['Companies', sid, 'logo']));
    }
    constructor(companyId: number, name:string, description:string, logo:string) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.logo = logo;
    }
}
```

Немного приблизился к решению теперь вопрос, каким условием проверить что пришло?

```js
class Departament {
    //{ "departament_ID": 1, "name": "Отдел1", "company_id": 1 }
    departamentId: number;
    name: string;
    companyId: number;
    constructor(x: { name: string; departamentId: number; companyId: number; }[]);
    constructor(x: { bd: LocalDb; id: number; }[]);
    constructor(x) {

        var sid = String(x.id);
        this.departamentId = Number(x.bd.getInfo(['Departaments', sid, 'departament_ID']));
        this.name = String(x.bd.getInfo(['Departaments', sid, 'name']));
        this.companyId = Number(x.bd.getInfo(['Departaments', sid, 'company_id']));

    }
}
```

Comment: Оформите картинку в виде текста, пожалуйста. В этом вопросе нет необходимости в картинке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так же, как и любой другой метод:

```
class LocalDb {
    getInfo(x : [any]) {}
}

class Company {
    //Companies": [ { "company_ID": 1, "name": "Компания1", "description": "Описание компании", "logo": "Лого" } 
    companyId: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    logo: string;

    constructor(bd: LocalDb, id: number)
    constructor(companyId: number, name:string, description:string, logo:string)
    constructor(companyId, name, description?, logo?) {
        if (typeof name === "number") {
            var bd = companyId as LocalDb;
            var id = name as number;

            var sid = String(id);
            this.companyId = Number(bd.getInfo(['Companies', sid, 'company_ID']));
            this.name = String(bd.getInfo(['Companies', sid, 'name']));
            this.description = String(bd.getInfo(['Companies', sid, 'description']));
            this.logo = String(bd.getInfo(['Companies', sid, 'logo']));
        } else {
            this.companyId = companyId;
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
            this.logo = logo;
        }
    }
}
```

Компилируется без ошибок, вроде и работать должно :)
http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Answer (score 1):

Решение пока что такое

```
class Departament {
    //{ "departament_ID": 1, "name": "Отдел1", "company_id": 1 }
    departamentId: number;
    name: string;
    companyId: number;
    constructor(x: { constr:string; name: string; departamentId: number; companyId: number; });
    constructor(x: { constr:string; bd: LocalDb; id: number; });
    constructor(x) {
        if (x.constr === 'new') {
            this.departamentId = x.departamentId;
            this.name = x.name;
            this.companyId = x.companyId;
        }else if(x.constr === 'fdb'){
            var sid = String(x.id);
            this.departamentId = Number(x.bd.getInfo(['Departaments', sid, 'departament_ID']));
            this.name = String(x.bd.getInfo(['Departaments', sid, 'name']));
            this.companyId = Number(x.bd.getInfo(['Departaments', sid, 'company_id']));
        }
    }
}
```